# How to create user based virtual subdomains in a module based application in Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: php, zend-framework, virtual, subdomain

I am creating an application on zend framework 1.12 I have a user module which accepts a user login and registration from "www.example.com". After validating the user I want to redirect the user to user specific subdomain "username.example.com". I already have configured my hosts file and apache's vhost file.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way which i have used in my project for multiple subdomains;

In `index.php` file extract the subdomain name (if exists any) and set it into a constant variable. This will be used later.

```
function extract_domain($domain) {
    if(preg_match("/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i", $domain, $matches)) {
        return $matches['domain'];
    } else {
        return $domain;
    }
}
function extract_subdomains($domain) {
    $subdomains = $domain;
    $domain = extract_domain($subdomains);
    $subdomains = str_replace('www', '', rtrim(strstr($subdomains, $domain, true), '.'));
    return $subdomains;
}

$subDomainName = extract_subdomains($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
//this const will be used in bootstrap file.
define('SUBDOMAIN_NAME', $subDomainName);
```

After `login` save the name of the sub domain in a session variable on which you want to redirect a user. You can write below function in the `bootstap` file of `user` module:

```
protected function _initSubdomainCheck() {
    //Get session in your own way for below line. I'm using action helper to manage the session.
    $userSession = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('siteSession')->getUserSession();
    $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
    //check if user is logged in then redirect user to a subdomain
    if(isset ( $userSession->logged_in ) && $userSession->logged_in == 1) {
        //SUBDOMAIN_NAME is a const variable i have set in index.php. If user is already redirected to the subdomain which is stored in session then no need to have further redirection
        if($userSession->urlSubDomainName != SUBDOMAIN_NAME) {
            $redirector->gotoUrl(Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('common')->getAfterLoginUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

Logic behind above function:

1. Get the session variable
2. Check whether user is logged in or not
3. If user is logged in then check if user is already on a subdomain URL, if no then redirect user to a specific sub domain.

I have created an action helper `common` in `/application/helpers/Common.php` with below code:
Method of this action helper can be called in this way:     `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('common')->methodName();`

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Common extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract{

    public function getSiteUrl(){
        $baseUrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
        return $this->getServerProtocol().$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $baseUrl;
    }

    public function getServerProtocol() {
        $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        return $protocol;
    }

    function extract_domain($domain) {
        if(preg_match("/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i", $domain, $matches)) {
           return $matches['domain'];
         } else {
           return $domain;
         }
     }

    public function getSubdomainName() {
        //get session object in your way.
        $session = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('siteSession')->getUserSession();
        $domainName = extract_domain($this->getSiteUrl());
        return $this->getServerProtocol()
            .$session->urlSubDomainName.'.'
            .$domainName;
    }
    public function getAfterLoginUrl(){
        return $this->getSubdomainName().'/yourController/Youraction';
    }

}
```

Logic for above helper:

1. We have written this helper to get the subdomain url. First we are getting the subdomain name from the `session` e.g. `abc`
2. After that extract the domain name. For e.g. if you have `www.example.com` then get `example.com` out of it.
3. Finally create the subdomain url `Protocol + subdomain name + domain name`. E.g. `http://abc.example.com`
4. return this URL.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

ZF1 has a hostname route type: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname. The example in the docs covers your exact use case.